# I accidently removed my Xbox 360's USB

Tags: xbox-360

I accidentally removed my USB stick from my Xbox 360 while it was on.

I had saved games, profiles, and downloaded games on that USB. When I plugged it back in the Xbox said that I had to format the USB drive.

My question is that when I format my drive will it erase all of my Xbox stuff?

Comment: Since the data on your stick is probably not gone, but can very well disappear in the hands of an inexperienced user, I would strongly recommend finding someone who's computer-savvy to take a look at the stick. They might be able to "repair" the stick from a PC without formatting, or recover the data from the stick before trying to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you format a USB drive on Xbox it **will** erase everything on that USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't erase the stick. In this case your savegames will be lost.

I'm sure that your xBox don't recognize the stick as it was removed while it's in use. Many file systems have a marker in it to display if a stick was previously in use.

You can reset these markers by removing them properly. In your case, your xBox is the only thing which can read it, I would recommend to try the stick on a linux and remove the stick savely. Normally it should reset the flag. As far as I see, it is a kind of FAT32 file system which is used, you can try to load it on your windows PC and remove it savely. Be sure you won't format it, if your windows will ask you for this.

After that try it again on your xbox.

By the way, if your not sure what your doing, you can take a complete image of the raw usb-image as a backup to restore it if you fail. If your not so experienced, ask a friend which has good computer knowledge to do it for you.